# Expected resource type to be one of id, id

Tags: android, listview

activity_criminals_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_criminals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.yourivanmill.csi.CriminalsList">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CriminalsList.java

```
package com.yourivanmill.csi;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CriminalsList extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_criminals_list);

        //final String[] criminals = getResources().getStringArray()
        final String[] crimials = { "Charles Zwolsman", "Etienne Urka", "Cor Van Hout" };

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_criminals_list);

        listView.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        crimials
                )
        );
    }
}
```

The following line

`ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_criminals_list);`

give a an error: Expected resource type to be one of id, id ...

In another activity when i use the findViewById method it works...

My api version is 23!

Comment: What is the id of your listview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line you are passing the id of the whole layout:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_criminals_list);
```

And you try to init `ListView` with it's ID, whose name is different from the layout name:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning id **activity_criminals_list** to **LinearLayout** in your XML and in java class you are trying to cast as **ListView**

change your layout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.yourivanmill.csi.CriminalsList">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_criminals_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It still crashes... ``java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yourivanmill.csi/com.yourivanmill.csi.CriminalsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference``

Comment: Doesn't mater what kind of activity i choose from ``R.layout.blabla`` it keeps saying the above message

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a whole layout to listview which isn't possible. The solution is to change the `R.layout.activity_criminals_list` into a view id.
Something like this `R.id.myList` and change your listview reference code to ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

Complete solution
add this to activity_criminals_list.xml

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then add this to CriminalsList.java

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_criminals_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You forgot to add id to ListView, in the xml.